# Multiple While loops in java method

Tags: java

I have a java method which writes content into a text file with values de-limited by | symbol. Contents needs to be picked up from 10 tables depending on conditions and write into file. Currently am doing the following method. Could anyone please suggest a better alternate approach for doing this requirement. Does this method have performance bottleneck

```
    public static void createFile()
    {
        queryFromTable1
        whileLoopForqueryFromTable1
        {
            writer.write(value1+"|"+value2+"|".....)
        }
        queryFromTable2
        whileLoopForqueryFromTable2
        {
            writer.write("||||"+value4+"|".....)
        }
        queryFromTable2
        whileLoopForqueryFromTable2
        {
            writer.write("||"+value5+"|".....)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your pseudo code is not clear, you don't explain what's the logic behind the number of pipes you're using as delimiters, further, according to your logic, `value5` won't necessarily show up right after `value4`

Comment: I think this belongs to to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: and how about trying a stringbuffer?

Answer (score 0):

A possible bottleneck is if any of the queries are slow, in that case all of the remaining queries have to wait for the earlier to complete. Another possible bottleneck is that the algorithm is single threaded.

To solve that a solution would be to do the reads in parallel and process the writing in multiple writers. When all of that has been completed, simply merge the writers in the correct order (single threaded). The Java 8 class `CompletableFuture` provides some nice features that can be used here. Simply create some futures that completes and merge the output.

Check out the [CompletableFuture JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) for more info.

An example of the algorithm could be something like code below. Please note that this is simply an example and not a full-fledged solution. The use of the `StringWriter` is just for convencience and is just *one* way of handling the data.

```
public class AlgorithmTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        // Setup async processing of task 1
        final CompletableFuture<String> q1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            // Setup result data
            StringWriter result = new StringWriter();

            // execute query 1

            // Process result
            result.write("result from 1");

            // Return the result (can of course be handled in other ways).
            return result.toString();
        });

        // Setup async processing of task 2
        final CompletableFuture<String> q2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            // Setup result data
            StringWriter result = new StringWriter();

            // execute query 2

            // Process result
            result.write("result from 2");

            // Return the result (can of course be handled in other ways).
            return result.toString();
        });

        // Write the whole thing to file (i.e. merge the streams)
        final Path path = new File("result.txt").toPath();
        Files.write(path, Arrays.asList(q1.get(), q2.get()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The writers are writing to a file, you can't parallelize *that*. But the basic idea is fine: parallelize the reads, merge the results into one object and write the aggregated results once you're done, using a single "write" action

Comment: @alfasin - Exactly (I wrote about that like 1 sec before you commented ;). The merge of writers must be somehow synchronized (single-threaded) but the individual writes can be parallel before the merge.

Comment: Isn't `write` writing data to buffer and then `write.flush` write the buffer to disk? Do we really need parallelisation?

Comment: @gkiko - That it depends on which writer you use. I mean, if you process reads and writes in parallel and the writes is e.g. a StreamWriter the separate writes are stored in memory. Then you can merge the separate streams to some kind of file stream.

Comment: @gkiko - I have updated the answer with an example to clarify what I aimed for.

Comment: You state the bottlenecks are possible, which implies they are not definite. (how can they be, as this is pseudocode). I consider it a waste of resources to optimize , especially restructure the code, based on a feeling

Comment: @Joeblade - agreed! But if there were bottlenecks due to e.g. slow queries a parallel approach will probably help.

Comment: @wassgren now I understand your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate method for extracting data from tables

```
private List<String> getDataFromTable("select * from table1"){...}
```

The obvious bottleneck is string concatenation `value1+"|"+value2+"|"`. You'd better use single `write` for each element

```
for(int i=0;i<tableData.size();i++){
   String str = tableData.get(i);
   if(checkPassed(str)){
      writer.write(str);
      // don't print last |
      if(i<tableData.size()-1)writer.write(DELIMITER); // private static final String DELIMITER = "|";
   }
}
```

More information will allow us to give better answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance bottleneck in this pseudo code.

If you are using a [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) I think it's ok to call write many times. You just have to not forget to close the writer at the end of treatments.

Now we don't know what is behind your DB query. Maybe they can be optimized. Do you use [`Prepared Statements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking down to several methods, below is pseudo code:

```
void createFile() {
    writeTo(out, query1);
    writeTo(out, query2);
    writeTo(out, query3);
    ....
}

void writeTo(out, query) {
    execute query
    loop(){
      out.write(...)
    }
}
```